# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean nameavailable as request attribute

Tags: java, forms, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here's my form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="header :: head"></head>
<body>
<div th:replace="header :: head-nav"></div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div th:each="catFeatGroup,status : ${catFeatGroupList}" class="form-group">
                <label>Position</label><input th:field="$   {catFeatGroupList[__${status.index}__].position}"  th:value="${catFeatGroup.position}" />
                <label>Name</label> <input name="${catFeatGroupList[__${status.index}__].name}" th:value="${catFeatGroup.name}" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div th:replace="footer :: foot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the controller that gives it values

```
    @RequestMapping("/category/edit/{id}")
    @ModelAttribute("catFeatGroupList")
    @org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
    public ModelAndView displayCategoryList(@PathVariable("id")Integer id){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("category-form");
        List<CatFeatGroup> catFeatGroupList = catFeatGroupService.findGroupsForCategory(id);
        mav.addObject("catFeatGroupList",catFeatGroupList);
        return  mav;
    }
}
```

However the page returns an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'catFeatGroupList[0]' available as request attribute
```

What am I missing

Answer (score 0):

The expression `th:field="${catFeatGroupList[__${status.index}__].position}"` is creating the error.

The `th:field` attribute can only be used within a html `form` tag, to access the fields of the defined form. 
`th:field` attribute generates 3 html attributes, `id`, `name` and `value`.

So your code can be modified as :

```
<div th:each="catFeatGroup,status : ${catFeatGroupList}" class="form-group">
    <label>Position</label>
    <input th:id="${'catFeatGroupList'+__${status.index}__+'.position'}" th:name="${'catFeatGroupList['+__${status.index}__+'].position'}" th:value="${catFeatGroup.position}" />
    <label>Name</label>
    <input th:id="${'catFeatGroupList'+__${status.index}__+'.name'}"     th:name="${'catFeatGroupList['+__${status.index}__+'].name'}" th:value="${catFeatGroup.name}" />
</div>
```

I have used `th:id`, `th:name` and `th:value` instead of `th:field`.

If a html `form` tag available, you can use `th:field`, instead of using `th:id`, `th:name` and `th:value` like this

```
<form th:object="${modelObject}">
    <div th:each="catFeatGroup,status : *{catFeatGroupList}" class="form-group">
        <label>Position</label>
        <input th:field="*{catFeatGroupList[__${status.index}__].position}" />
        <label>Name</label>
        <input th:field="*{catFeatGroupList[__${status.index}__].name}" />
    </div>
</form>
```